# Are nested composable declarations considered as an antipattern?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

What are the differences in these two apart from not having to pass all the variables in nested calls? Are there any performance differences?

```kotlin
/// Approach 1: Nested declarations
@Composable
fun MyView1(currentNum: Int) {
    @Composable
    fun InnerView(num: Int) {
         Text(
              "$num",
              color = if (currentNum == num) Color.Red else Color.Black
         )
    }
    for (i in 0..currentNum) {
        InnerView(i)
    }
}

/// Approach 2: Normal top level declarations
@Composable
fun MyView2(currentNum: Int) {
    for (i in 0..currentNum) {
        InnerView(i, currentNum)
    }
}
@Composable
fun InnerView(num: Int, currentNum: Int) {
    Text(
        "$num",
        color = if (currentNum == num) Color.Red else Color.Black
    )
}
```